# How to apply operation to each row after looking up info from another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am new to R and was wondering how to do the following:
I have a data frame called 'wage' which has features like

```
First.Name Last.Name Hourly.Pay
Lara       Davis     39.29
John       Childers  35.12
Lara       Grace     40.16
```

In 'wage' the first name can be non-unique. I have another data frame called 'wage_gender' which has features like

```
name gender ProbMale ProbFemale
Lara Female 0.0088   0.9912
John Male   0.992    0.008
```

The 'name' is wage_gender are all unique and should correspond to the First.Name in 'wage'. The two data frames are not of the same size. *Also, some names in wage may not be there in wage gender. So, it should get set to NA.*
I want to add a 'gender' feature to the 'wage' data frame by looking up the genders from 'wage_gender'. However i can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I have

```
f = function(r, gen)
r$gender = gen[which(gen$name == r$First.Name),]$gender
apply(wage, 1, f, gen=wage_gender)
```

Basically, I expect apply to use 'f' over each row and look for the name in 'wage_gender' and assign the appropriate gender but it throws an error: `Error in r$First.Name : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you share your data?

Comment: data as in? example of rows in the data frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different way to do this is to add the names as row.names in `wage_gender` and then just use that as a lookup table.

```
row.names(wage_gender) = wage_gender$name
wage_gender[wage$First.Name, "gender"]
[1] "Female" "Male"   "Female"
```

That will also give NA if the name is not in `wage_gender`

Comment: Great solution! I was basically looking for a hashmap. I come from a C++ background and it was not obvious how this works in R.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the column 'name' as 'first.name' in 'wage_gender'

```
names(wage_gender)[i] <- "First.Name" #(where i is the number of the column that has 'name' as name)
```

You can also rename like that (it's more elegant, but longer):

```
names(wage_gender)[names(wage_gender == "name")] = "First.Name"
```

And then, merge the two data.frame:

```
new.df <- merge(wage_gender,wage,by ="First.Name")
```

Comment: The first.name in 'wage' are not unique. They are unique in 'wage_gender' And these data frames are not of the same size.

Comment: if they are not the same size, it's not a big problem, just check that you get what you want in the end with this, it should work. As for names not being unique in 'wage', that may not be a problem if you just want to apply to each name the gender (even if they are repeated)

Comment: Tried this. It almost works. The problem is, some names in 'wage' don't appear in 'wage_gender', in which case gender should get set to 'na' but I think this is getting rid of those rows. Also, the merge is causing 'ProbMale' and ProbFemale to also get added to wage, which I did not want. I can get rid of them if there is no other way.